# listagg - multiple group by columns

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm using `LISTAGG` with a lot of columns.

So I have to do `GROUP BY` all those columns.

Is there a tidier way to do this ?

Like 'group by all minus listagg...' ?

Comment: Could you possibly post some example code?

Comment: There is no tidier way. You must list all columns in the GROUP BY clause (apart from constants, aggregates, and some expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example table? Are you joining tables. This example uses a join, but the LISTAGG columns are not in the group by statement.

Here's an example I worked on for another question that I edited.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1733/13/0)

```
SELECT c.id,
   c.model,
   LISTAGG(d.name, ',')
     within GROUP (ORDER BY d.name)  AS "Drivers",
   LISTAGG(c.color, ',')
     within GROUP (ORDER BY c.color) AS "Colors"
FROM   TBLCARS c
   join TBLDRIVERS d
     ON c.id = d.fid_tblcars
GROUP  BY c.id,
      c.model
ORDER  BY c.id
```

Here's one using the WITH clause as well to you use CTE and build a larger query.

```
WITH cte
 AS (SELECT c.id,
            LISTAGG(c.color, ',')
              within GROUP (ORDER BY c.color) AS "Colors",
            LISTAGG(c.model, ',')
              within GROUP (ORDER BY c.model) AS "Model",
            LISTAGG(d.name, ',')
              within GROUP (ORDER BY d.name)  AS "Name"
     FROM   TBLCARS c
            join TBLDRIVERS d
              ON c.id = d.fid_tblcars
     GROUP  BY c.id)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
```

[SQL FIDDLE WITH](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1733/45/0)

Comment: I wish the person who downed my answer would explain the reasoning. I have little experience with Oracle SQL, but my answer appeared on track as I used LISTAGG with none of those columns in the GROUP BY statement.. I didn't have any example code, so I gave it my best shot. Any information on why would helpful for future reference. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I uped your question.

Comment: I downvoted. There's nothing particularly wrong with your SQL, but it doesn't answer the question.